# 757: unexpected token a t 'Ã¯Â»Â¿{ (JSON::ParserError)

Tags: ruby

I'm getting a ParserError when running a Ruby script which generates translated HTML files from a JSON file. The encoding of the JSON file is ISO-8859-1, but when I run the ruby code I get the following:

```
:marker=>true}
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/json/common.rb:155:in `parse': 757: unexpected token a
t 'Ã¯Â»Â¿{ (JSON::ParserError)
    "de_DE": {
        "1": "HERBST 2013",
        "2": "STILSICHER",
                "3": "Klassisch geschnittene AnzÃƒÂ¼ge",
                "4": "PERFEKT KOMBINIERT",
                "5": "Business hemden mit klasse",
                "6": "HERBST 2013",
                "7": "CASUAL BIS COCKTAIL",
                "8": "Vielseitige Kleider",
                "9": "SPORTIV BIS ELEGANT",
                "10": "MÃƒÂ¤ntel mit Anspruch",
                "11": "ELEGANZ NACH MASS",
                "12": "Unverwechselbare",
                "13": "PASSGENAU",
                "14": "Perfekt geschnittene Blazer"
    },
    "en_GB": {
        "1": "FALL 2013",
        "2": "PURE STYLE",
...............
```

IS it changing the foreign characters for some reason?

In the ruby script I have:

```
translation_hash = JSON.parse(File.read('translation_master.json').force_encoding("ISO-8859-1").encode("utf-8", replace: nil))
```

http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/d17fd

json file here:

http://alexanderlloyd.info/json/translation_master.json

Comment: Please read http://sscce.org/ then provide a summarized sample of your JSON that replicates the problem. Don't link to it as link-rot will eventually set in making your question worthless.

Comment: According to [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com), your JSON is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

Are you reading the file as UTF8? Ruby 1.9 will assume that files are UTF-8 unless told otherwise.

```
JSON.parse open("input.json", "r:iso-8859-1:utf-8").read
```

This will specify that the file contains ISO-8859-1 encoding, then transcodes it to UTF-8 as it's being read.

If you can supply a test file, it may be easier to help debug.

Comment: see the updated post I added a ruby fiddle too so you can see the ruby code, bytheway I'm a front end dev, don't know ruby at all really.

Comment: Can you provide a raw sample of the translation JSON file that's failing?

Comment: The data as provided is UTF-8. Your ä is encoded as a two-byte character, `303 274`, which is indicative of UTF-8. In ISO-8859-1, this would be a single byte, `228`. See https://gist.github.com/cheald/5970601 for the hexdump. Forcing it to ISO-8859-1 is going to mangle the encoding. Just remove your `force_encoding` and `encode` stuff and you should be fine.

Comment: I removed this but still get same error .force_encoding("ISO-8859-1").encode("utf-8", replace: nil)

Comment: `JSON.parse(open("data.json", "r").read)` works just fine here with the data provided. Perhaps the error lies elsewhere?

Comment: could it be my version of Ruby? I'm using 2.0.0

Comment: or maybe missing this parser or a gem or something: require 'optparse' # option parser

Answer (score 2):

First at all, this guy [jadala](https://twitter.com/jalada) is the author of what I'm saying here.

**Some background**

Latin1 is a character encoding used by MySQL. People mistakenly think it is equivalent to ISO-8859-1 but it isn’t, it’s actually CP-1252 (also known as Windows-1252). CP-1252 is a superset of ISO-8859-1 with some additional characters (recently including the € symbol).

Try to apply this:

```
def fix_cp1252_utf8(text)
    text.encode('cp1252',
        :fallback => {
            "\u0081" => "\x81".force_encoding("cp1252"),
            "\u008D" => "\x8D".force_encoding("cp1252"),
            "\u008F" => "\x8F".force_encoding("cp1252"),
            "\u0090" => "\x90".force_encoding("cp1252"),
            "\u009D" => "\x9D".force_encoding("cp1252")
          })
  .force_encoding("utf-8")
end
```

Take a look here:

[Solving Latin1 and UTF8 errors for good in Ruby](http://jalada.co.uk/2011/12/07/solving-latin1-and-utf8-errors-for-good-in-ruby.html)

[Ruby 1.9 Encodings: A Primer and the Solution for Rails](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/05/05/ruby-1-9-encodings-a-primer-and-the-solution-for-rails/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll do it.